# why do you have to pay 720 dollars to register new truck but only 36 dollars for an old car?

Tags: car, fees

Why do you have to pay 720 dollars to register a new truck but only 36 dollars for an old car?

Answer (score 3):

Countries/States/Counties/Cities vary wildly on tax/fee policies. A lot of taxes/fees are progressive, people that can afford new cars can afford a higher registration fee, just like people with higher income pay higher income tax rates.

Some regions charge extra fees for larger vehicles because they put more wear on infrastructure than smaller vehicles, and/or because they want to discourage usage of high-consumption vehicles.

This, along with depreciation and cost to insure, is another reason why typically it is most cost-effective to purchase used vehicles.